# Liferay URL problems

Tags: liferay

I am a little confused by Liferay's friendly URL mechanism and utility classes.

Can someone please explain this URL to me in detail?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/web/guest/home
^      ^         ^    ^   ^     ^                     
Prot.  Hostname  |    |   |  Layout FriendlyURL
                Port  |  Sitename 
                     ???
```

Part 4 *web* is a miracle to me and seems to be indicating if the site is staged, public or private?

The next question would be, which UtilClass to use to guarantee that a certain layout exists in that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the `web` part indicates the the site is public and for private pages ot would be `group`.
To check if a layout exists get the `friendlyUrl` of the `layout` use :

```
LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLLayout(long groupId, boolean privateLayout, String friendlyURL)
```

If this doesn't suit you there are other methods in this class that may.

Liferay Doc: [LayoutLocalServiceUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/LayoutLocalServiceUtil.html)

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the groupId from the friendlyUrl somehow?

Comment: I think this should do `GroupLocalServiceUtil.getFriendlyURLGroup(long companyId, String friendlyURL)  `

Comment: And how to retrieve to companyId?

Comment: Sorry don't get me wrong, but I only have the url and need to find out about company, group, layout, etc. How does Liferay do it itself?

Comment: If you are on a request, let's say RenderRequst, you get companyId from ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = 
     (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
themeDisplay.getCompanyId();
Liferay has all this stored in DB (companyId, groupId, layoutId) so it knows where to look and also a url belongs to only one companyId, groupId and layoutId.

Comment: but the problem is, that I am building a 404 error page and I only have a HttpServletRequest :(

Comment: Maybe this will do PortletRequest request= (PortletRequest) request.getAttribute("javax.portlet.request");